# Why do we need "Set Variable"?

Tags: robotframework

I am wondering if there is any fundamental difference between those two lines below:

```
${SERVER}     www.google.co.nz
${SERVER}=    Set Variable    www.google.co.nz
```

In both cases, we assign variable &{SERVER} with a value of "www.google.co.nz". Why do we need to use "Set Variable" if we can assign a variable without it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first form can only be used in a variable table, the second form can only be used in keywords and test cases. `Set Variable` is required if you want to set a variable dynamically.

Comment: Thanks. @Bryan Oakley.

Comment: Could you explain the "Variable Table" please ? I googled for it, but with no success on a reasonable explanation.

Comment: @borgmater: no need to google it, just read the robot framework user guide. http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-table